# математические операции дроби с целым числом

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как сделать так чтобы можно было проводить операции не только с дробями но и целого числа с дробью. Сейчас выдает ошибку, недостаток атрибутов.

Код:

```
class Fraction:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.a) + "/" + str(self.b)

    def show(self):
        print(self.a, '/', self.b, sep='')

    def __add__(self, otherfraction):
        
        newnum = self.a * otherfraction.b + self.b * otherfraction.a
        newden = self.b * otherfraction.b
        print(str(newnum) + '/' + str(newden))
        return Fraction(newnum, newden)

    def __sub__(self, otherfraction):
        newnum = self.a * otherfraction.b - self.b * otherfraction.a
        newden = self.b * otherfraction.b
        print(str(newnum) + '/' + str(newden))
        return Fraction(newnum, newden)

    def __mul__(self, otherfraction):
        newnum = self.a * otherfraction.a
        newden = self.b * otherfraction.b
        print(str(newnum) + '/' + str(newden))
        return Fraction(newnum, newden)

    def __truediv__(self, otherfraction):
        newnum = self.a * otherfraction.b
        newden = self.b * otherfraction.a
        print(str(newnum) + '/' + str(newden))
        return Fraction(newnum, newden)


class OperationsOnFraction(Fraction):

    def getint(self):
        integer = self.a // self.b
        print(integer)
        return integer

    def getfloat(self):
        float_number = self.a / self.b
        print(float_number)
        return float_number


first_fraction = Fraction(1, 2)
second_fraction = Fraction(3, 4)
Fraction.__add__(first_fraction, second_fraction)
Fraction.__sub__(first_fraction, second_fraction)
Fraction.__mul__(first_fraction, second_fraction)
Fraction.__truediv__(first_fraction, second_fraction)


x = OperationsOnFraction(2, 3)
x.getint()
x.getfloat()
```

Comment: Добавьте строку кода, которая выдаёт ошибку. Приведённый код ошибок не выдаёт. Ну и опишите - какие именно операции вы хотите делать с целыми числами и дробями и с каким порядком аргументов.

Comment: @oleksandr_ievlakhov, вы можете пометить ответ как решение, если он вам подходит или  дополнить свой вопрос, если текущий ответ не то что вы искали)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может быть переводить целое числов дробь, если второй аргумент не передан, то принимается за 1.

```
class Fraction:
    def __init__(self, a, b=1):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b 
    ...

a = Fraction(3)
```

И дальше работать как с обычной дробью

Comment: Кстати, очень хороший вариант

Comment: спасибо большое, все работает